# MacBook Air issues on ubuntu 20.04 (overheat, battery, trackpad, sound and screen color)

Tags: sound, touchpad, battery, macbook, overheating

EDITED:  below is the output for   ***lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'***

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 6000 (rev 09)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. HD Graphics 6000
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

I have MacBook Air 2017 model with the cpu "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5350U CPU @ 1.80GHz"
I am running ubuntu 20.04, the following issues:

1- Overheat: my Mac is overheated, almost all the time, from the moment it's booted till I turn it off, regardless of opening an app or not. I did install **macfanctld** and it did reduce it, but it is still very hot compared to what I had on macOS

2- Baterry life is considerably shorter around 1.5-2.0 hours shorter than it was on macOS, I also noticed that my battery never gets fully charged, when it gets around 89-90 percent, it says it is fully charged.

3- trackpad glitches and it isn't smooth, sometimes feels laggy (still usable)

4- the sound is lower than it was on macOS and noticeably distorted when I get it to max Volume.

5- the screen colors feels odd, more like not very well calibrated, I can feel more warmness in the colors sometimes and the opposite other times (more cooler colors)
 when watching videos online.

I would appreciate any kind of help for anyone of these issues.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 
Thx and done.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: I thought that was more convenient, edited now.